# Java does not diffrince between 2 Strings variables array of object (Update)

Tags: java, string, class, object, variables

This problem related to my previous problem here:

[Java does not differ between 2 String variables in array of objects for loop proplem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52906280/java-does-not-differ-between-2-string-variables-in-array-of-objects-for-loop-pro?noredirect=1#comment92723206_52906280)

@JB Nizet has given me this link and marked my problem as duplicated: [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

but I tried to do the what they said and it does not work well, you can see what I did as they said:

3- Main Class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BookTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

       // 1. making array of books (Array of objects):
       Book[] books= new Book[3];

       //2. store the values into an array of objects:

        for (int i = 0; i <books.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter book "+ (i+1)+ " title: ");
            String title=input.nextLine();
            input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter book "+(i+1)+" author's name:");
            String name=input.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter book "+ (i+1)+ " price: ");
            double price=input.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("Enter book "+(i+1)+" author's email: ");
            String email=input.next();

            Author a=new Author(name,email);

            books[i]=new Book(title,price,a);

            System.out.println(books[i]+"\n");

        }

    }

}
```

as you can see I added an input.nextLine(); line between the String title=input.nextLine(); and System.out.println("Enter book "+(i+1)+" author's name:"); but nothing happens, it let me enter the both values, but when the object is printed , the title is missed!

look at the run :
[image]

Waiting for your help
and thank you very much

Comment: i tried to understand the title of the question, but i can not get it.

Comment: Your question **is** an exact duplicate, you need to understand this to move forward. You are mixing line oriented input with non-line oriented input. The `input.nextLine();` needs to be after `input.nextDouble();` (because **that** leaves a trailing newline - 20.0 doesn't contain `\n`). **Or**, *alternatively* **always** use `input.nextLine()` and parse the `double`, `int`, or whatever yourself - that avoids the problem.

Comment: `String email=input.next();` **and** `double price=input.nextDouble();` are enumerated ***examples*** in *is skipping `nextLine()` after using `next()` or `nextFoo()`*

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Frisch I can't understand, if you can show me by code because I can't understand by theory instructions, i will be so thankful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly as it says in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13102066/2970947) to [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045/2970947), you have to consume the trailing new line after every next() or nextFoo(). Like,

```
for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
    System.out.print("Enter book " + (i + 1) + " title: ");
    String title = input.nextLine();
    // NOT HERE. input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter book " + (i + 1) + " author's name:");
    String name = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter book " + (i + 1) + " price: ");
    double price = input.nextDouble(); // next or nextFoo
    input.nextLine(); // Scanner is skipping nextLine

    System.out.println("Enter book " + (i + 1) + " author's email: ");
    String email = input.next(); // next or nextFoo
    input.nextLine(); // Scanner is skipping nextLine
    Author a = new Author(name, email);
    books[i] = new Book(title, price, a);
    System.out.println(books[i] + "\n");
}
```

**or**, as also suggested in that excellent answer, **parse** the input yourself and ***always*** use `nextLine()`. Like,

```
for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
    System.out.print("Enter book " + (i + 1) + " title: ");
    String title = input.nextLine();
    // NOT HERE. input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter book " + (i + 1) + " author's name:");
    String name = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter book " + (i + 1) + " price: ");
    String pr = input.nextLine();
    double price = Double.parseDouble(pr);

    System.out.println("Enter book " + (i + 1) + " author's email: ");
    String email = input.nextLine();
    Author a = new Author(name, email);
    books[i] = new Book(title, price, a);
    System.out.println(books[i] + "\n");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you let me understand what happens!